# Hide text besides post image when sharing a post from my website to facebook

Tags: facebook, post, text, share, sharing

Here is my website: http://www.hotaphrodite.com/

When someone tries to share a post to facebook, there's always a weird text (meta tags I guess) that goes with the post. I wanna know how to hide it. Here is what I'm talking about: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hotaphrodite.com%2F%3Fp%3D297&t
I want to hide the text that appears besides the image: "Posted onOctober 3, 2012byHot AphroditeTweetThis entry was posted inBrunettesand taggedbeautiful,brunette,girl,gorgeous,hot,womanbyHot Aphrodite. Bookmark thepermalink."

I already contacted some wordpress developers and I was informed that this is an issue with facebook, not wordpress, so the only way to solve it is through facebook, but I guess that maybe there's some code editing that I could do on wordpress to avoid this text from appearing when someone shares a post. So, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was messing with the sharing URL and i got this for example:

[https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hotaphrodite.com%2F%3Fp](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.hotaphrodite.com/?p)

But it appears to erase the very nice picture of the website.